# AutocompleteExtender inside gridview

Tags: ajax, gridview

I am using an autocomplete extender inside a gridview. Inside the gridview, I have a country dropdown. When I select a country, the states should be populated in the autocomplete extender using textbox.

I am able to populate the countries and states. But when I have multiple rows in the gridview,

1. I select a country in row 1 of the gridview.
2. But all the StatesTextbox are updated with the states based on this selection. i.e, I am not able to choose which textbox/row should be updated on Dropdown selected event.

Could anyone help me on this issue? Appreciate your response!!

Comment: You can improve this question by including the programming language you're using and some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the context key of the autocompleteextender to the dropdownlist selected value and retrieved the value when I typein something in the statesearch textbox.